# Testing/Knowing element to be deleted when backspacing in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, dom, contenteditable, rangy

I'm using a contenteditable-based rich text editor, and am adding the idea of "inline comments".

I want the comments to be editable inline and also collapsable by clicking a toggle.

The markup would be something like

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable='true'>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2 <q class="inline-comment" tabindex="1"><span class="comment" tabindex="2">This is a comment</span><span class="inline-comment-control"><</span></q> This is more content.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
</div>
```

And the comments are collapsable by clicking the `.inline-comment-control':

```
$('#editor').delegate('.inline-comment-control', "click", function() {$(this).closest('.inline-comment').toggleClass('collapsed')});
```

I have a simple jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bJELv/

My challenge is that when the user has the cursor to the right of the comment and backspaces (or opposite for "delete"), the collapse toggle gets deleted.

What I'd like to happen is that the entire `.inline-comment` and all its children are deleted monolithically.

So, I'd like to be able to know what is about to be deleted by the backspace key.

Being a contenteditable DIV, this is proving to be difficult because of the myriad of behaviors that may happen.  It basically seems like I would have to duplicate the logic that the browser uses to determine what to do (merge siblings, deleting the last child of the parents previous sibling, etc).  I've tried using Rangy to determine what's preceding the selection, but I keep running across edge cases where differing markup adds complexity (the comment is inside a  tag, for instance, or something similar).

I'm pretty sure that there's no way to easily extract the behavior of the backspace key, so an alternate question is, "Is there a better way to deal with not deleting the span.inline-comment-control while still leaving the span.comment simply editable"?

Or, is there a good description of what browsers are supposed to do with the backspace on contenteditable, so I CAN reproduce it in JS?

I'm really only interested in targeting relatively modern browsers (no IE < 9, etc), and are using jquery and rangy.

I've spent quite a bit of time searching through SO, and there are a number of somewhat related questions, but I've found nothing that directly relates to this question.

Comment: Hehe :) I was implementing recently very similar thing in CKEditor. This code will not be usable for you, but may give some ideas: https://github.com/cksource/ckeditor-dev/blob/t/9764/core/selection.js#L356-L384

Comment: And if you want to see how that works check `/plugins/widgetimage/dev/widgetimage.html` and `/plugins/widgettime/dev/widgettime.html` from `t/9764` branch.

Comment: Was going to ask - "range.getPreviousNode()/range.getNextNode()" - do you have a custom Range class - which you do:  https://github.com/cksource/ckeditor-dev/blob/t/9764/core/dom/range.js#L1893

Looking into that...

Comment: Yes, we have :) Forgot to mention that this implementation still have problems on Firefox with bogus `<br>`s. I wasn't sure how to handle them, so this part is awaiting better times.